# Magento Controller deprecated action class confusion

Tags: magento2.4

On Magento 2.4 i found this class extends (extends **\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action**) show deprecated.

**Ref : Screenshot at end of the question**

But Magento core use this code. I mean in core code they extends this class.

As per knowledge if a code get deprecated then on next release it may get removed, so there must be alternative code for the deprecated code. How can we easily found alternative for list of deprecated code in Magento 2?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This approach is deprecated because of the favor of composition over inheritance.

So instead of:

```php
class YourClass extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
```

use:

```php
class YourClass implements \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface
```

and add your logic to the `execute()` method.

It's true though that there's still a lot of Magento core code that uses the deprecated approach. So this will not be removed soon, if they will ever do.

---

**Edited Date :- 3rd June, 2022**
you can use `Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface` directly but, as per Magento standard, you should use the HTTP Method interface (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) as per your request type

> 1. `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface`
> 2. `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface`
> 3. `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPutActionInterface`
> 4. `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpDeleteActionInterface`

These **Http*HTTP Method*ActionInterface** interfaces extends \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface.

your sample controller should look like this

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Display implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    private $pageFactory;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(PageFactory $pageFactory, RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Get the params that were passed from our Router
        // echo $firstParam = $this->request->getParam('first_param', null);

        return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

for more details about routing action class [**see here at Magento docs**](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/routing/#action-class)

Comment: Thank you for a simple explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late with the answer.

In Magento 2.4 Action classes are implementations of the ActionInterface that a router returns on matched requests. The execute() function in these classes contain the logic for dispatching requests.

More details can be found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#action-class)